# Using required/provided interfaces in component diagrams plantuml

Tags: interface, components, diagram, plantuml

I want to include needed/provided interfaces in my component diagram in PlantUML, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation how this is possible. Can anybody help?
Thanks

rein

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please show what you would like to have / what you already tried.

Answer (score 18):

```
@startuml
[Component] -right-( Interface
[AnotherComponent] -left- Interface
@enduml
```

will be rendered as:

[image]